# Setting TERM enviroment variable

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to change the terminal type to the one with no colors support (for e.g `linux-m`). To achive this i've set the TERM environment variable like so:

`export TERM="linux-m"`

But it seems do nothing - `ls -l` still gives me colorized results

Answer (score 0):

Following should to the trick:

```
unset LS_COLORS; export TERM=vt220
```

Terminal type `xterm` or `linux` is like superset of `vt220`. It supports colours. If you want to compare features of terminal types, use utility `infocmp`, like:

```
infocmp xterm vt220
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit of why this works?